# Problems in proportion of a graph display

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to display true data using the following graph, but I'm having some difficulties:

**Less important, but if possible:**

1. The X-axis should be from 0 to 1000 in jumps of 100 (i.e. 0, 100, 200, 300, etc.) and not like now (100, 199, 298, etc.).
2. The Y-axis should be from 0 to 15,000 in jumps of 1000 (i.e. 0, 1000, 2000, etc.), but if I increase ymax from 9999 I get an error.

**More important:**

At about 80 points out of 700 points along the X-axis, the blue bar is slightly below the red bar. You can barely see it. I would love if there is a way to display the graph so that the same points can be seen as far as possible (even if not all of them, at least it will be noticeable that it happens occasionally.). No problem changing the height, width, rulers, colors, etc., just do not change the data.

Thanks!

[image: Problems in proportion of a graph display]

**My code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15,width=20cm,height=20cm,scale=0.6}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1000,
    xtick={1,100,...,1000},
    xlabel={\sf \scriptsize Series length (days)},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=9999,
    ytick={0,3000,...,15000},
    ylabel={\sf \scriptsize Total bits},
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed, /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,precision=0},
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
    legend style={nodes={scale=0.6, transform shape},
    fill opacity=0.6,
    draw opacity=1,
    text opacity=1,
    at={(0.58,-0.45)}, anchor=south, draw=none},
    cycle list name=exotic,
    mark size=1.5,
    legend pos= outer north east,
    legend style={draw=none},
]
\addplot [red, mark size=1, mark=none, line width = 1pt, thick] plot coordinates{
(40,280)(41,297)(42,316)(43,335)(44,354)(45,368)(46,383)(47,398)(48,413)(49,432)(50,450)(51,463)(52,476)(53,487)(54,500)(55,511)(56,522)(57,533)(58,544)(59,554)(60,565)(61,577)(62,589)(63,600)(64,610)(65,621)(66,631)(67,641)(68,651)(69,662)(70,672)(71,682)(72,692)(73,702)(74,711)(75,720)(76,728)(77,738)(78,746)(79,756)(80,764)(81,773)(82,781)(83,789)(84,798)(85,806)(86,815)(87,823)(88,831)(89,839)(90,848)(91,856)(92,864)(93,872)(94,880)(95,888)(96,897)(97,905)(98,913)(99,921)(100,929)(101,937)(102,945)(103,954)(104,962)(105,970)(106,978)(107,987)(108,996)(109,1004)(110,1013)(111,1022)(112,1031)(113,1039)(114,1048)(115,1057)(116,1066)(117,1075)(118,1084)(119,1094)(120,1104)(121,1113)(122,1123)(123,1132)(124,1141)(125,1150)(126,1161)(127,1171)(128,1181)(129,1192)(130,1201)(131,1210)(132,1221)(133,1233)(134,1244)(135,1256)(136,1268)(137,1279)(138,1290)(139,1304)(140,1318)(141,1334)(142,1351)(143,1366)(144,1380)(145,1395)(146,1412)(147,1431)(148,1449)(149,1469)(150,1488)(151,1505)(152,1521)(153,1537)(154,1552)(155,1568)(156,1585)(157,1600)(158,1615)(159,1628)(160,1644)(161,1661)(162,1678)(163,1695)(164,1711)(165,1724)(166,1737)(167,1754)(168,1771)(169,1788)(170,1804)(171,1818)(172,1830)(173,1842)(174,1858)(175,1873)(176,1889)(177,1905)(178,1920)(179,1932)(180,1945)(181,1961)(182,1977)(183,1992)(184,2007)(185,2022)(186,2034)(187,2047)(188,2062)(189,2078)(190,2091)(191,2104)(192,2117)(193,2129)(194,2140)(195,2154)(196,2168)(197,2182)(198,2196)(199,2210)(200,2221)(201,2233)(202,2248)(203,2262)(204,2278)(205,2294)(206,2309)(207,2322)(208,2336)(209,2352)(210,2369)(211,2387)(212,2405)(213,2423)(214,2438)(215,2454)(216,2474)(217,2495)(218,2514)(219,2534)(220,2554)(221,2572)(222,2587)(223,2605)(224,2628)(225,2652)(226,2678)(227,2705)(228,2726)(229,2743)(230,2755)(231,2773)(232,2793)(233,2812)(234,2829)(235,2843)(236,2857)(237,2873)(238,2889)(239,2904)(240,2919)(241,2933)(242,2945)(243,2957)(244,2971)(245,2984)(246,2998)(247,3010)(248,3023)(249,3034)(250,3046)(251,3058)(252,3071)(253,3083)(254,3095)(255,3107)(256,3118)(257,3129)(258,3141)(259,3153)(260,3165)(261,3176)(262,3188)(263,3199)(264,3211)(265,3223)(266,3235)(267,3246)(268,3258)(269,3270)(270,3281)(271,3292)(272,3304)(273,3316)(274,3327)(275,3339)(276,3351)(277,3362)(278,3374)(279,3386)(280,3397)(281,3409)(282,3421)(283,3433)(284,3444)(285,3456)(286,3468)(287,3480)(288,3492)(289,3504)(290,3516)(291,3527)(292,3539)(293,3552)(294,3564)(295,3576)(296,3589)(297,3601)(298,3613)(299,3626)(300,3638)(301,3651)(302,3664)(303,3677)(304,3690)(305,3702)(306,3715)(307,3728)(308,3742)(309,3756)(310,3769)(311,3783)(312,3796)(313,3810)(314,3825)(315,3840)(316,3855)(317,3870)(318,3885)(319,3898)(320,3913)(321,3929)(322,3946)(323,3962)(324,3979)(325,3996)(326,4011)(327,4027)(328,4046)(329,4066)(330,4084)(331,4103)(332,4122)(333,4138)(334,4155)(335,4176)(336,4196)(337,4216)(338,4236)(339,4256)(340,4272)(341,4288)(342,4309)(343,4328)(344,4348)(345,4366)(346,4384)(347,4397)(348,4413)(349,4433)(350,4451)(351,4470)(352,4488)(353,4505)(354,4519)(355,4535)(356,4555)(357,4574)(358,4592)(359,4610)(360,4628)(361,4641)(362,4657)(363,4675)(364,4692)(365,4709)(366,4725)(367,4740)(368,4753)(369,4768)(370,4784)(371,4799)(372,4814)(373,4829)(374,4843)(375,4855)(376,4870)(377,4885)(378,4901)(379,4916)(380,4931)(381,4945)(382,4958)(383,4972)(384,4987)(385,5003)(386,5018)(387,5032)(388,5045)(389,5058)(390,5072)(391,5085)(392,5099)(393,5112)(394,5126)(395,5139)(396,5151)(397,5164)(398,5177)(399,5190)(400,5202)(401,5215)(402,5227)(403,5240)(404,5252)(405,5264)(406,5276)(407,5288)(408,5299)(409,5311)(410,5322)(411,5333)(412,5345)(413,5356)(414,5368)(415,5379)(416,5390)(417,5401)(418,5413)(419,5424)(420,5435)(421,5447)(422,5458)(423,5469)(424,5480)(425,5491)(426,5502)(427,5514)(428,5525)(429,5536)(430,5547)(431,5558)(432,5569)(433,5580)(434,5592)(435,5603)(436,5614)(437,5625)(438,5636)(439,5647)(440,5658)(441,5669)(442,5680)(443,5692)(444,5703)(445,5714)(446,5725)(447,5736)(448,5747)(449,5758)(450,5769)(451,5780)(452,5791)(453,5802)(454,5813)(455,5824)(456,5835)(457,5846)(458,5857)(459,5868)(460,5879)(461,5890)(462,5901)(463,5912)(464,5923)(465,5934)(466,5945)(467,5957)(468,5968)(469,5979)(470,5990)(471,6001)(472,6012)(473,6023)(474,6034)(475,6045)(476,6056)(477,6067)(478,6078)(479,6089)(480,6100)(481,6111)(482,6122)(483,6133)(484,6144)(485,6155)(486,6166)(487,6177)(488,6188)(489,6199)(490,6210)(491,6221)(492,6232)(493,6243)(494,6254)(495,6265)(496,6276)(497,6287)(498,6298)(499,6310)(500,6321)(501,6332)(502,6343)(503,6354)(504,6366)(505,6377)(506,6388)(507,6400)(508,6411)(509,6422)(510,6434)(511,6445)(512,6457)(513,6468)(514,6480)(515,6491)(516,6502)(517,6514)(518,6526)(519,6538)(520,6550)(521,6562)(522,6573)(523,6585)(524,6597)(525,6610)(526,6622)(527,6634)(528,6647)(529,6659)(530,6671)(531,6684)(532,6697)(533,6711)(534,6724)(535,6737)(536,6750)(537,6763)(538,6778)(539,6792)(540,6807)(541,6821)(542,6836)(543,6850)(544,6864)(545,6882)(546,6898)(547,6915)(548,6932)(549,6949)(550,6964)(551,6980)(552,7000)(553,7019)(554,7038)(555,7056)(556,7075)(557,7091)(558,7109)(559,7130)(560,7150)(561,7170)(562,7190)(563,7210)(564,7228)(565,7246)(566,7267)(567,7289)(568,7311)(569,7333)(570,7353)(571,7369)(572,7386)(573,7408)(574,7425)(575,7440)(576,7459)(577,7479)(578,7500)(579,7519)(580,7540)(581,7557)(582,7573)(583,7587)(584,7601)(585,7617)(586,7633)(587,7649)(588,7663)(589,7678)(590,7693)(591,7708)(592,7721)(593,7735)(594,7750)(595,7763)(596,7777)(597,7791)(598,7804)(599,7817)(600,7831)(601,7844)(602,7857)(603,7871)(604,7884)(605,7897)(606,7909)(607,7922)(608,7935)(609,7948)(610,7961)(611,7973)(612,7986)(613,7999)(614,8011)(615,8024)(616,8037)(617,8049)(618,8061)(619,8074)(620,8086)(621,8099)(622,8111)(623,8123)(624,8136)(625,8148)(626,8160)(627,8172)(628,8185)(629,8197)(630,8209)(631,8222)(632,8234)(633,8246)(634,8258)(635,8270)(636,8283)(637,8295)(638,8307)(639,8319)(640,8332)(641,8344)(642,8356)(643,8368)(644,8380)(645,8393)(646,8405)(647,8417)(648,8429)(649,8442)(650,8454)(651,8466)(652,8478)(653,8491)(654,8503)(655,8515)(656,8527)(657,8539)(658,8550)(659,8562)(660,8573)(661,8585)(662,8596)(663,8608)(664,8619)(665,8631)(666,8643)(667,8655)(668,8666)(669,8677)(670,8689)(671,8701)(672,8712)(673,8724)(674,8736)(675,8748)(676,8759)(677,8771)(678,8783)(679,8796)(680,8808)(681,8820)(682,8833)(683,8845)(684,8858)(685,8872)(686,8886)(687,8901)(688,8917)(689,8933)(690,8948)(691,8966)(692,8987)(693,9010)(694,9031)(695,9052)(696,9075)(697,9098)(698,9125)(699,9157)(700,9192)(701,9228)(702,9264)(703,9298)(704,9332)(705,9376)(706,9423)(707,9471)(708,9520)(709,9569)(710,9613)(711,9658)(712,9711)(713,9764)(714,9813)(715,9859)(716,9899)(717,9937)(718,9973)(719,10022)(720,10067)(721,10101)(722,10129)(723,10153)(724,10175)(725,10197)(726,10223)(727,10246)(728,10269)(729,10291)(730,10311)(731,10329)(732,10346)(733,10367)(734,10386)(735,10404)(736,10422)(737,10439)(738,10455)(739,10471)
};
\addlegendentry{\small \sc red}
\addplot [blue, mark size=1, mark=none, line width = 1pt, thick] coordinates{
(40,280)(41,292)(42,304)(43,316)(44,352)(45,365)(46,378)(47,391)(48,404)(49,417)(50,454)(51,466)(52,478)(53,490)(54,502)(55,514)(56,526)(57,538)(58,550)(59,560)(60,572)(61,584)(62,596)(63,608)(64,618)(65,630)(66,640)(67,650)(68,660)(69,672)(70,682)(71,692)(72,702)(73,712)(74,722)(75,732)(76,740)(77,750)(78,758)(79,768)(80,776)(81,786)(82,794)(83,802)(84,812)(85,820)(86,830)(87,838)(88,846)(89,854)(90,864)(91,872)(92,880)(93,888)(94,896)(95,904)(96,914)(97,922)(98,930)(99,938)(100,946)(101,954)(102,962)(103,972)(104,980)(105,988)(106,996)(107,1006)(108,1016)(109,1024)(110,1034)(111,1044)(112,1054)(113,1062)(114,1072)(115,1082)(116,1092)(117,1102)(118,1112)(119,1122)(120,1132)(121,1142)(122,1152)(123,1162)(124,1172)(125,1182)(126,1194)(127,1204)(128,1214)(129,1226)(130,1236)(131,1246)(132,1258)(133,1270)(134,1282)(135,1294)(136,1306)(137,1318)(138,1330)(139,1342)(140,1354)(141,1368)(142,1382)(143,1396)(144,1408)(145,1422)(146,1436)(147,1450)(148,1464)(149,1478)(150,1492)(151,1506)(152,1564)(153,1579)(154,1592)(155,1607)(156,1622)(157,1635)(158,1648)(159,1661)(160,1676)(161,1691)(162,1706)(163,1721)(164,1736)(165,1749)(166,1762)(167,1777)(168,1792)(169,1807)(170,1822)(171,1835)(172,1848)(173,1861)(174,1876)(175,1889)(176,1904)(177,1919)(178,1932)(179,1945)(180,1958)(181,1973)(182,1988)(183,2001)(184,2014)(185,2027)(186,2040)(187,2053)(188,2066)(189,2081)(190,2154)(191,2168)(192,2182)(193,2194)(194,2206)(195,2220)(196,2234)(197,2248)(198,2262)(199,2276)(200,2288)(201,2300)(202,2314)(203,2328)(204,2342)(205,2356)(206,2370)(207,2384)(208,2398)(209,2412)(210,2428)(211,2444)(212,2460)(213,2476)(214,2490)(215,2504)(216,2520)(217,2536)(218,2552)(219,2568)(220,2584)(221,2600)(222,2614)(223,2630)(224,2646)(225,2662)(226,2680)(227,2698)(228,2714)(229,2730)(230,2742)(231,2825)(232,2842)(233,2859)(234,2874)(235,2889)(236,2904)(237,2919)(238,2934)(239,2949)(240,2964)(241,2979)(242,2992)(243,3005)(244,3020)(245,3033)(246,3048)(247,3061)(248,3074)(249,3085)(250,3098)(251,3111)(252,3124)(253,3137)(254,3150)(255,3163)(256,3174)(257,3185)(258,3198)(259,3211)(260,3224)(261,3235)(262,3248)(263,3259)(264,3272)(265,3285)(266,3298)(267,3309)(268,3322)(269,3335)(270,3346)(271,3357)(272,3370)(273,3383)(274,3394)(275,3407)(276,3420)(277,3431)(278,3444)(279,3457)(280,3468)(281,3481)(282,3494)(283,3507)(284,3518)(285,3531)(286,3544)(287,3557)(288,3570)(289,3583)(290,3596)(291,3607)(292,3620)(293,3633)(294,3646)(295,3659)(296,3672)(297,3685)(298,3698)(299,3711)(300,3724)(301,3737)(302,3750)(303,3763)(304,3776)(305,3789)(306,3802)(307,3815)(308,3830)(309,3845)(310,3858)(311,3873)(312,3886)(313,3901)(314,3916)(315,3931)(316,3946)(317,3961)(318,3976)(319,3989)(320,4004)(321,4019)(322,4034)(323,4049)(324,4064)(325,4079)(326,4094)(327,4109)(328,4126)(329,4143)(330,4160)(331,4177)(332,4194)(333,4209)(334,4224)(335,4241)(336,4258)(337,4275)(338,4292)(339,4309)(340,4324)(341,4339)(342,4356)(343,4373)(344,4390)(345,4407)(346,4424)(347,4437)(348,4452)(349,4469)(350,4486)(351,4503)(352,4520)(353,4535)(354,4550)(355,4565)(356,4582)(357,4599)(358,4616)(359,4633)(360,4650)(361,4663)(362,4678)(363,4695)(364,4710)(365,4725)(366,4740)(367,4755)(368,4768)(369,4783)(370,4798)(371,4813)(372,4828)(373,4843)(374,4858)(375,4871)(376,4886)(377,4901)(378,4916)(379,4931)(380,4946)(381,4961)(382,4974)(383,4989)(384,5004)(385,5019)(386,5144)(387,5158)(388,5172)(389,5186)(390,5200)(391,5214)(392,5228)(393,5242)(394,5256)(395,5270)(396,5282)(397,5296)(398,5310)(399,5324)(400,5336)(401,5350)(402,5362)(403,5376)(404,5388)(405,5293)(406,5306)(407,5319)(408,5330)(409,5343)(410,5354)(411,5365)(412,5378)(413,5389)(414,5402)(415,5413)(416,5424)(417,5435)(418,5448)(419,5459)(420,5470)(421,5483)(422,5494)(423,5505)(424,5516)(425,5527)(426,5538)(427,5551)(428,5562)(429,5573)(430,5584)(431,5595)(432,5606)(433,5617)(434,5630)(435,5641)(436,5652)(437,5663)(438,5674)(439,5685)(440,5696)(441,5707)(442,5718)(443,5731)(444,5742)(445,5753)(446,5764)(447,5775)(448,5786)(449,5797)(450,5808)(451,5819)(452,5830)(453,5841)(454,5852)(455,5863)(456,5874)(457,5885)(458,5896)(459,5907)(460,5918)(461,5929)(462,5940)(463,5951)(464,5962)(465,5973)(466,5984)(467,5997)(468,6008)(469,6019)(470,6030)(471,6041)(472,6052)(473,6063)(474,6074)(475,6085)(476,6096)(477,6107)(478,6118)(479,6129)(480,6140)(481,6151)(482,6162)(483,6173)(484,6184)(485,6195)(486,6206)(487,6217)(488,6228)(489,6239)(490,6250)(491,6261)(492,6272)(493,6283)(494,6294)(495,6305)(496,6316)(497,6327)(498,6338)(499,6351)(500,6362)(501,6373)(502,6384)(503,6395)(504,6408)(505,6419)(506,6430)(507,6443)(508,6454)(509,6465)(510,6478)(511,6489)(512,6502)(513,6513)(514,6526)(515,6537)(516,6548)(517,6561)(518,6574)(519,6587)(520,6600)(521,6613)(522,6624)(523,6637)(524,6650)(525,6663)(526,6676)(527,6689)(528,6702)(529,6715)(530,6728)(531,6741)(532,6754)(533,6769)(534,6782)(535,6795)(536,6808)(537,6821)(538,6836)(539,6851)(540,6866)(541,6881)(542,6896)(543,6911)(544,6926)(545,6943)(546,6958)(547,6973)(548,6988)(549,7003)(550,7018)(551,7033)(552,7050)(553,7067)(554,7084)(555,7101)(556,7118)(557,7133)(558,7150)(559,7167)(560,7184)(561,7201)(562,7218)(563,7235)(564,7252)(565,7269)(566,7286)(567,7303)(568,7320)(569,7337)(570,7354)(571,7369)(572,7384)(573,7401)(574,7416)(575,7431)(576,7448)(577,7465)(578,7482)(579,7499)(580,7698)(581,7714)(582,7730)(583,7744)(584,7758)(585,7774)(586,7790)(587,7806)(588,7820)(589,7836)(590,7852)(591,7868)(592,7882)(593,7896)(594,7912)(595,7926)(596,7940)(597,7954)(598,7968)(599,7982)(600,7996)(601,8010)(602,8024)(603,8038)(604,8052)(605,8066)(606,8078)(607,8092)(608,8106)(609,8120)(610,8134)(611,8146)(612,8160)(613,8174)(614,8186)(615,8200)(616,8214)(617,8226)(618,8238)(619,8252)(620,8264)(621,8278)(622,8290)(623,8302)(624,8316)(625,8328)(626,8340)(627,8352)(628,8366)(629,8378)(630,8390)(631,8404)(632,8416)(633,8428)(634,8440)(635,8452)(636,8466)(637,8478)(638,8490)(639,8502)(640,8516)(641,8528)(642,8540)(643,8552)(644,8564)(645,8578)(646,8590)(647,8602)(648,8614)(649,8628)(650,8640)(651,8652)(652,8664)(653,8678)(654,8690)(655,8702)(656,8518)(657,8531)(658,8542)(659,8555)(660,8566)(661,8579)(662,8590)(663,8603)(664,8614)(665,8627)(666,8640)(667,8653)(668,8664)(669,8675)(670,8688)(671,8701)(672,8712)(673,8725)(674,8738)(675,8751)(676,8762)(677,8775)(678,8788)(679,8801)(680,8814)(681,8827)(682,8840)(683,8853)(684,8866)(685,8881)(686,8896)(687,8911)(688,8926)(689,8941)(690,8956)(691,8973)(692,8990)(693,9210)(694,9228)(695,9246)(696,9264)(697,9282)(698,9302)(699,9322)(700,9342)(701,9362)(702,9382)(703,9402)(704,9422)(705,9444)(706,9466)(707,9488)(708,9510)(709,9532)(710,9554)(711,9576)(712,9598)(713,9620)(714,9642)(715,9664)(716,9684)(717,9704)(718,9724)(719,9746)(720,9768)(721,10105)(722,10126)(723,10145)(724,10164)(725,10183)(726,10202)(727,10221)(728,10240)(729,10259)(730,10278)(731,10295)(732,10312)(733,10331)(734,10348)(735,10365)(736,10382)(737,10399)(738,10416)(739,10433)
};
\addlegendentry{\small blue}
\addplot [yellow, mark size=1, mark=none, line width = 1pt, thick] coordinates{
(40,288)(41,301)(42,314)(43,327)(44,362)(45,376)(46,390)(47,404)(48,418)(49,432)(50,463)(51,475)(52,487)(53,499)(54,511)(55,523)(56,535)(57,547)(58,559)(59,570)(60,582)(61,594)(62,606)(63,618)(64,629)(65,641)(66,652)(67,663)(68,674)(69,686)(70,697)(71,708)(72,719)(73,730)(74,741)(75,752)(76,760)(77,771)(78,779)(79,790)(80,798)(81,809)(82,817)(83,825)(84,836)(85,844)(86,855)(87,863)(88,871)(89,879)(90,890)(91,898)(92,906)(93,914)(94,922)(95,930)(96,941)(97,949)(98,957)(99,965)(100,973)(101,981)(102,989)(103,1000)(104,1008)(105,1016)(106,1024)(107,1035)(108,1046)(109,1054)(110,1065)(111,1076)(112,1087)(113,1095)(114,1106)(115,1117)(116,1128)(117,1139)(118,1150)(119,1161)(120,1172)(121,1183)(122,1194)(123,1205)(124,1216)(125,1227)(126,1239)(127,1250)(128,1261)(129,1273)(130,1284)(131,1295)(132,1307)(133,1319)(134,1331)(135,1343)(136,1355)(137,1367)(138,1379)(139,1391)(140,1403)(141,1418)(142,1433)(143,1448)(144,1460)(145,1475)(146,1490)(147,1505)(148,1520)(149,1535)(150,1550)(151,1565)(152,1626)(153,1642)(154,1655)(155,1671)(156,1687)(157,1700)(158,1713)(159,1726)(160,1742)(161,1758)(162,1774)(163,1790)(164,1806)(165,1819)(166,1832)(167,1848)(168,1864)(169,1880)(170,1896)(171,1909)(172,1922)(173,1935)(174,1951)(175,1964)(176,1980)(177,1996)(178,2009)(179,2022)(180,2035)(181,2051)(182,2067)(183,2080)(184,2093)(185,2106)(186,2119)(187,2132)(188,2145)(189,2161)(190,2217)(191,2231)(192,2245)(193,2258)(194,2271)(195,2285)(196,2299)(197,2313)(198,2327)(199,2341)(200,2354)(201,2367)(202,2381)(203,2395)(204,2409)(205,2423)(206,2437)(207,2451)(208,2465)(209,2479)(210,2496)(211,2513)(212,2530)(213,2547)(214,2561)(215,2575)(216,2592)(217,2609)(218,2626)(219,2643)(220,2660)(221,2677)(222,2691)(223,2708)(224,2725)(225,2742)(226,2760)(227,2778)(228,2795)(229,2812)(230,2825)(231,2919)(232,2937)(233,2955)(234,2970)(235,2985)(236,3000)(237,3015)(238,3030)(239,3045)(240,3060)(241,3075)(242,3089)(243,3103)(244,3118)(245,3132)(246,3147)(247,3161)(248,3175)(249,3186)(250,3200)(251,3214)(252,3228)(253,3242)(254,3256)(255,3270)(256,3281)(257,3292)(258,3306)(259,3320)(260,3334)(261,3345)(262,3359)(263,3370)(264,3384)(265,3398)(266,3412)(267,3423)(268,3437)(269,3451)(270,3462)(271,3473)(272,3487)(273,3501)(274,3512)(275,3526)(276,3540)(277,3551)(278,3565)(279,3579)(280,3590)(281,3604)(282,3618)(283,3632)(284,3643)(285,3657)(286,3671)(287,3685)(288,3699)(289,3713)(290,3727)(291,3738)(292,3752)(293,3766)(294,3780)(295,3794)(296,3808)(297,3822)(298,3836)(299,3850)(300,3864)(301,3878)(302,3892)(303,3906)(304,3920)(305,3934)(306,3948)(307,3962)(308,3977)(309,3992)(310,4006)(311,4021)(312,4035)(313,4050)(314,4065)(315,4080)(316,4095)(317,4110)(318,4125)(319,4139)(320,4154)(321,4169)(322,4184)(323,4199)(324,4214)(325,4229)(326,4244)(327,4259)(328,4277)(329,4295)(330,4313)(331,4331)(332,4349)(333,4364)(334,4379)(335,4397)(336,4415)(337,4433)(338,4451)(339,4469)(340,4484)(341,4499)(342,4517)(343,4535)(344,4553)(345,4571)(346,4589)(347,4603)(348,4618)(349,4636)(350,4654)(351,4672)(352,4690)(353,4705)(354,4720)(355,4735)(356,4753)(357,4771)(358,4789)(359,4807)(360,4825)(361,4839)(362,4854)(363,4872)(364,4887)(365,4902)(366,4917)(367,4932)(368,4946)(369,4961)(370,4976)(371,4991)(372,5006)(373,5021)(374,5036)(375,5050)(376,5065)(377,5080)(378,5095)(379,5110)(380,5125)(381,5140)(382,5154)(383,5169)(384,5184)(385,5199)(386,5300)(387,5315)(388,5330)(389,5345)(390,5360)(391,5375)(392,5390)(393,5405)(394,5420)(395,5435)(396,5447)(397,5462)(398,5477)(399,5492)(400,5504)(401,5519)(402,5531)(403,5546)(404,5558)(405,5484)(406,5498)(407,5512)(408,5523)(409,5537)(410,5548)(411,5559)(412,5573)(413,5584)(414,5598)(415,5609)(416,5620)(417,5631)(418,5645)(419,5656)(420,5667)(421,5681)(422,5692)(423,5703)(424,5714)(425,5725)(426,5736)(427,5750)(428,5761)(429,5772)(430,5783)(431,5794)(432,5805)(433,5816)(434,5830)(435,5841)(436,5852)(437,5863)(438,5874)(439,5885)(440,5896)(441,5907)(442,5918)(443,5932)(444,5943)(445,5954)(446,5965)(447,5976)(448,5987)(449,5998)(450,6009)(451,6020)(452,6031)(453,6042)(454,6053)(455,6064)(456,6075)(457,6086)(458,6097)(459,6108)(460,6119)(461,6130)(462,6141)(463,6152)(464,6163)(465,6174)(466,6185)(467,6199)(468,6210)(469,6221)(470,6232)(471,6243)(472,6254)(473,6265)(474,6276)(475,6287)(476,6298)(477,6309)(478,6320)(479,6331)(480,6342)(481,6353)(482,6364)(483,6375)(484,6386)(485,6397)(486,6408)(487,6419)(488,6430)(489,6441)(490,6452)(491,6463)(492,6474)(493,6485)(494,6496)(495,6507)(496,6518)(497,6529)(498,6540)(499,6554)(500,6565)(501,6576)(502,6587)(503,6598)(504,6612)(505,6623)(506,6634)(507,6648)(508,6659)(509,6670)(510,6684)(511,6695)(512,6709)(513,6720)(514,6734)(515,6745)(516,6756)(517,6770)(518,6784)(519,6798)(520,6812)(521,6826)(522,6837)(523,6851)(524,6865)(525,6879)(526,6893)(527,6907)(528,6921)(529,6935)(530,6949)(531,6963)(532,6977)(533,6992)(534,7006)(535,7020)(536,7034)(537,7048)(538,7063)(539,7078)(540,7093)(541,7108)(542,7123)(543,7138)(544,7153)(545,7171)(546,7186)(547,7201)(548,7216)(549,7231)(550,7246)(551,7261)(552,7279)(553,7297)(554,7315)(555,7333)(556,7351)(557,7366)(558,7384)(559,7402)(560,7420)(561,7438)(562,7456)(563,7474)(564,7492)(565,7510)(566,7528)(567,7546)(568,7564)(569,7582)(570,7600)(571,7615)(572,7630)(573,7648)(574,7663)(575,7678)(576,7696)(577,7714)(578,7732)(579,7750)(580,7901)(581,7917)(582,7933)(583,7948)(584,7963)(585,7979)(586,7995)(587,8011)(588,8026)(589,8042)(590,8058)(591,8074)(592,8089)(593,8104)(594,8120)(595,8135)(596,8150)(597,8165)(598,8180)(599,8195)(600,8210)(601,8225)(602,8240)(603,8255)(604,8270)(605,8285)(606,8297)(607,8312)(608,8327)(609,8342)(610,8357)(611,8369)(612,8384)(613,8399)(614,8411)(615,8426)(616,8441)(617,8453)(618,8465)(619,8480)(620,8492)(621,8507)(622,8519)(623,8531)(624,8546)(625,8558)(626,8570)(627,8582)(628,8597)(629,8609)(630,8621)(631,8636)(632,8648)(633,8660)(634,8672)(635,8684)(636,8699)(637,8711)(638,8723)(639,8735)(640,8750)(641,8762)(642,8774)(643,8786)(644,8798)(645,8813)(646,8825)(647,8837)(648,8849)(649,8864)(650,8876)(651,8888)(652,8900)(653,8915)(654,8927)(655,8939)(656,8811)(657,8825)(658,8836)(659,8850)(660,8861)(661,8875)(662,8886)(663,8900)(664,8911)(665,8925)(666,8939)(667,8953)(668,8964)(669,8975)(670,8989)(671,9003)(672,9014)(673,9028)(674,9042)(675,9056)(676,9067)(677,9081)(678,9095)(679,9109)(680,9123)(681,9137)(682,9151)(683,9165)(684,9179)(685,9194)(686,9209)(687,9224)(688,9239)(689,9254)(690,9269)(691,9287)(692,9305)(693,9465)(694,9484)(695,9503)(696,9522)(697,9541)(698,9561)(699,9581)(700,9601)(701,9621)(702,9641)(703,9661)(704,9681)(705,9702)(706,9723)(707,9744)(708,9765)(709,9786)(710,9807)(711,9828)(712,9849)(713,9870)(714,9891)(715,9912)(716,9932)(717,9952)(718,9972)(719,9993)(720,10014)(721,10363)(722,10384)(723,10404)(724,10424)(725,10444)(726,10464)(727,10484)(728,10504)(729,10524)(730,10544)(731,10561)(732,10578)(733,10598)(734,10615)(735,10632)(736,10649)(737,10666)(738,10683)(739,10700)
};
\addlegendentry{\small yellow}
\addplot [orange, mark size=1, mark=none, line width = 1pt, thick] coordinates{
(40,308)(41,319)(42,331)(43,343)(44,384)(45,396)(46,408)(47,420)(48,432)(49,445)(50,487)(51,499)(52,511)(53,522)(54,534)(55,545)(56,556)(57,567)(58,578)(59,589)(60,600)(61,612)(62,624)(63,635)(64,646)(65,657)(66,668)(67,679)(68,690)(69,701)(70,712)(71,723)(72,734)(73,745)(74,755)(75,765)(76,774)(77,785)(78,794)(79,805)(80,814)(81,824)(82,833)(83,842)(84,852)(85,861)(86,871)(87,880)(88,889)(89,898)(90,908)(91,917)(92,926)(93,935)(94,944)(95,953)(96,963)(97,972)(98,981)(99,990)(100,999)(101,1008)(102,1017)(103,1027)(104,1036)(105,1045)(106,1054)(107,1064)(108,1074)(109,1083)(110,1093)(111,1103)(112,1113)(113,1122)(114,1132)(115,1142)(116,1152)(117,1162)(118,1172)(119,1183)(120,1194)(121,1204)(122,1215)(123,1225)(124,1235)(125,1245)(126,1256)(127,1267)(128,1278)(129,1289)(130,1299)(131,1309)(132,1320)(133,1332)(134,1343)(135,1355)(136,1367)(137,1378)(138,1389)(139,1401)(140,1413)(141,1426)(142,1439)(143,1452)(144,1464)(145,1477)(146,1490)(147,1503)(148,1516)(149,1530)(150,1543)(151,1556)(152,1647)(153,1661)(154,1674)(155,1688)(156,1702)(157,1715)(158,1728)(159,1741)(160,1755)(161,1769)(162,1783)(163,1797)(164,1811)(165,1824)(166,1837)(167,1851)(168,1865)(169,1879)(170,1893)(171,1906)(172,1918)(173,1930)(174,1944)(175,1957)(176,1971)(177,1985)(178,1998)(179,2010)(180,2023)(181,2037)(182,2051)(183,2064)(184,2077)(185,2090)(186,2102)(187,2115)(188,2128)(189,2142)(190,2249)(191,2262)(192,2275)(193,2288)(194,2300)(195,2314)(196,2328)(197,2342)(198,2356)(199,2370)(200,2382)(201,2395)(202,2409)(203,2423)(204,2437)(205,2451)(206,2465)(207,2478)(208,2492)(209,2506)(210,2521)(211,2536)(212,2551)(213,2566)(214,2580)(215,2594)(216,2609)(217,2624)(218,2639)(219,2654)(220,2669)(221,2684)(222,2698)(223,2713)(224,2729)(225,2745)(226,2761)(227,2777)(228,2792)(229,2807)(230,2820)(231,2962)(232,2978)(233,2994)(234,3009)(235,3023)(236,3037)(237,3052)(238,3067)(239,3082)(240,3097)(241,3111)(242,3124)(243,3137)(244,3151)(245,3165)(246,3179)(247,3192)(248,3206)(249,3218)(250,3231)(251,3244)(252,3258)(253,3271)(254,3284)(255,3297)(256,3309)(257,3321)(258,3334)(259,3347)(260,3360)(261,3372)(262,3385)(263,3397)(264,3410)(265,3423)(266,3436)(267,3448)(268,3461)(269,3474)(270,3486)(271,3498)(272,3511)(273,3524)(274,3536)(275,3549)(276,3562)(277,3574)(278,3587)(279,3600)(280,3612)(281,3625)(282,3638)(283,3651)(284,3663)(285,3676)(286,3689)(287,3702)(288,3715)(289,3728)(290,3741)(291,3753)(292,3766)(293,3780)(294,3793)(295,3806)(296,3820)(297,3833)(298,3846)(299,3860)(300,3873)(301,3887)(302,3901)(303,3915)(304,3929)(305,3942)(306,3956)(307,3970)(308,3984)(309,3998)(310,4012)(311,4026)(312,4040)(313,4054)(314,4069)(315,4084)(316,4099)(317,4114)(318,4129)(319,4143)(320,4158)(321,4173)(322,4188)(323,4203)(324,4218)(325,4233)(326,4248)(327,4263)(328,4279)(329,4295)(330,4311)(331,4327)(332,4343)(333,4358)(334,4373)(335,4389)(336,4405)(337,4421)(338,4437)(339,4453)(340,4468)(341,4483)(342,4499)(343,4515)(344,4531)(345,4547)(346,4563)(347,4577)(348,4592)(349,4608)(350,4624)(351,4640)(352,4656)(353,4671)(354,4685)(355,4700)(356,4716)(357,4732)(358,4748)(359,4764)(360,4780)(361,4794)(362,4809)(363,4825)(364,4840)(365,4855)(366,4870)(367,4885)(368,4899)(369,4914)(370,4929)(371,4944)(372,4959)(373,4974)(374,4988)(375,5001)(376,5016)(377,5031)(378,5046)(379,5061)(380,5076)(381,5090)(382,5104)(383,5118)(384,5133)(385,5148)(386,5348)(387,5363)(388,5377)(389,5391)(390,5406)(391,5420)(392,5435)(393,5449)(394,5464)(395,5478)(396,5491)(397,5505)(398,5519)(399,5533)(400,5546)(401,5560)(402,5573)(403,5587)(404,5600)(405,5421)(406,5434)(407,5447)(408,5459)(409,5472)(410,5484)(411,5496)(412,5509)(413,5521)(414,5534)(415,5546)(416,5558)(417,5570)(418,5583)(419,5595)(420,5607)(421,5620)(422,5632)(423,5644)(424,5656)(425,5668)(426,5680)(427,5693)(428,5705)(429,5717)(430,5729)(431,5741)(432,5753)(433,5765)(434,5778)(435,5790)(436,5802)(437,5814)(438,5826)(439,5838)(440,5850)(441,5862)(442,5874)(443,5887)(444,5899)(445,5911)(446,5923)(447,5935)(448,5947)(449,5959)(450,5971)(451,5983)(452,5995)(453,6007)(454,6019)(455,6031)(456,6043)(457,6055)(458,6067)(459,6079)(460,6091)(461,6103)(462,6115)(463,6127)(464,6139)(465,6151)(466,6163)(467,6176)(468,6188)(469,6200)(470,6212)(471,6224)(472,6236)(473,6248)(474,6260)(475,6272)(476,6284)(477,6296)(478,6308)(479,6320)(480,6332)(481,6344)(482,6356)(483,6368)(484,6380)(485,6392)(486,6404)(487,6416)(488,6428)(489,6440)(490,6452)(491,6464)(492,6476)(493,6488)(494,6500)(495,6512)(496,6524)(497,6536)(498,6548)(499,6561)(500,6573)(501,6585)(502,6597)(503,6609)(504,6622)(505,6634)(506,6646)(507,6659)(508,6671)(509,6683)(510,6696)(511,6708)(512,6721)(513,6733)(514,6746)(515,6758)(516,6770)(517,6783)(518,6796)(519,6809)(520,6822)(521,6835)(522,6847)(523,6860)(524,6873)(525,6887)(526,6900)(527,6913)(528,6927)(529,6940)(530,6953)(531,6967)(532,6981)(533,6995)(534,7009)(535,7023)(536,7037)(537,7051)(538,7066)(539,7080)(540,7095)(541,7109)(542,7124)(543,7138)(544,7152)(545,7168)(546,7183)(547,7198)(548,7213)(549,7228)(550,7243)(551,7258)(552,7274)(553,7290)(554,7306)(555,7322)(556,7338)(557,7353)(558,7369)(559,7385)(560,7401)(561,7417)(562,7433)(563,7449)(564,7465)(565,7481)(566,7497)(567,7513)(568,7529)(569,7545)(570,7561)(571,7576)(572,7591)(573,7607)(574,7622)(575,7637)(576,7653)(577,7669)(578,7685)(579,7701)(580,8017)(581,8033)(582,8049)(583,8064)(584,8079)(585,8095)(586,8111)(587,8127)(588,8142)(589,8157)(590,8172)(591,8187)(592,8201)(593,8216)(594,8231)(595,8245)(596,8260)(597,8275)(598,8289)(599,8303)(600,8318)(601,8332)(602,8346)(603,8361)(604,8375)(605,8389)(606,8402)(607,8416)(608,8430)(609,8444)(610,8458)(611,8471)(612,8485)(613,8499)(614,8512)(615,8526)(616,8540)(617,8553)(618,8566)(619,8580)(620,8593)(621,8607)(622,8620)(623,8633)(624,8647)(625,8660)(626,8673)(627,8686)(628,8700)(629,8713)(630,8726)(631,8740)(632,8753)(633,8766)(634,8779)(635,8792)(636,8806)(637,8819)(638,8832)(639,8845)(640,8859)(641,8872)(642,8885)(643,8898)(644,8911)(645,8925)(646,8938)(647,8951)(648,8964)(649,8978)(650,8991)(651,9004)(652,9017)(653,9031)(654,9044)(655,9057)(656,8734)(657,8747)(658,8759)(659,8772)(660,8784)(661,8797)(662,8809)(663,8822)(664,8834)(665,8847)(666,8860)(667,8873)(668,8885)(669,8897)(670,8910)(671,8923)(672,8935)(673,8948)(674,8961)(675,8974)(676,8986)(677,8999)(678,9012)(679,9026)(680,9039)(681,9052)(682,9066)(683,9079)(684,9093)(685,9107)(686,9121)(687,9136)(688,9151)(689,9166)(690,9181)(691,9197)(692,9213)(693,9583)(694,9600)(695,9617)(696,9634)(697,9651)(698,9669)(699,9688)(700,9707)(701,9726)(702,9745)(703,9764)(704,9783)(705,9802)(706,9822)(707,9842)(708,9862)(709,9882)(710,9901)(711,9921)(712,9941)(713,9961)(714,9981)(715,10001)(716,10020)(717,10039)(718,10058)(719,10078)(720,10098)(721,10559)(722,10578)(723,10596)(724,10614)(725,10632)(726,10651)(727,10669)(728,10687)(729,10705)(730,10723)(731,10740)(732,10757)(733,10775)(734,10792)(735,10809)(736,10826)(737,10843)(738,10859)(739,10875)
};
\addlegendentry{\small orange}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the first minor thing, you want `xtick={0,100,...,1000},`. The dots notation works in the way that with `{a, b, ..., c}`, the separation between the numbers in the generated list is given by `b - a`. You have `1, 100, ..., 1000`, so the separation between ticks is 100 - 1 = 99.

Answer (score 1):

Many of your option contradicts or overwrites each other.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=1000,
    ymin=0, ymax=10000,
    xtick distance=100, ytick distance=1000,
    yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed, precision=0},
    scaled y ticks=false,
    xlabel={\sf \scriptsize Series length (days)},
    ylabel={\sf \scriptsize Total bits per day}, %tentative label
    tick label style={font=\scriptsize},
    legend style={nodes={scale=0.6}, draw=none},
    legend pos=north east,
%    y filter/.expression={y/x}, %uncomment for second plot and adjust min, max and ticks
]
\addplot [red] plot coordinates{
(40,280)(41,297)(42,316)(43,335)(44,354)(45,368)(46,383)(47,398)(48,413)(49,432)(50,450)(51,463)(52,476)(53,487)};
\addlegendentry{\small \sc red}
\addplot [blue] coordinates{
(40,280)(41,292)(42,304)(43,316)(44,352)(45,365)(46,378)(47,391)(48,404)(49,417)(50,454)(51,466)(52,478)(53,490)
};
\addlegendentry{\small blue}
\addplot [yellow] coordinates{
(40,288)(41,301)(42,314)(43,327)(44,362)(45,376)(46,390)(47,404)(48,418)(49,432)(50,463)(51,475)(52,487)(53,499)};
\addlegendentry{\small yellow}
\addplot [orange] coordinates{
(40,308)(41,319)(42,331)(43,343)(44,384)(45,396)(46,408)(47,420)(48,432)(49,445)(50,487)(51,499)(52,511)(53,522)};
\addlegendentry{\small orange}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with line plots]
[image: Graph]

Comment: You wrote two graphs in the answer, but attached a code of only one. When I copy it I get only graph skeleton without the colored lines in it.

Comment: Yes, I deleted your data - just insert it again. This site is for conceptual problems that others can benefit from. Concrete data is not part of that so please only add dummy data showing your problem. The second graph comes from uncomment `%    y filter/.expression={y/x}, %uncomment for second plot and adjust min, max and ticks`